# We are forced with IE 11 upgrade, any way to make it act like IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

Our IT department is automatically sending the IE11 upgrade to our PCs.  The task I perform needs IE8.

I have tried the compatibility mode on IE11 but it only allows me do limited tasks. I cannot downgrade to IE8.

Talking to our IT department is not an option.

Am I left with any other option here?

Comment: There are [free virtual machines with IE8](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) offered by Microsoft for exactly this purpose.  The body of your question is confusing, and the lack of accurate tags is concerning, you might want to take some time to improve your question.  There are also [alternatives](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/remote/) that do exist

Comment: Besides, shouldn't you be talking to your IT dept?

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks I have improved my question. & Puzbie that is not an option.

Comment: You are going to need to talk to your IT Department in order to implement any solution.  Since you have already determined that the compatibility mode within IE11 isn't enough.

Comment: @Ramhound it should be noted that the VMs are for website testing only, not for production use.

Comment: @chuex - I cannot think of any other type task, that would require a specific version of IE, and if there is then that still should be handled through IT.

Comment: @Ramhound yes agreed. Just noting it since OP does not mention what the task is.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing IE11, it didn't work. Then I went to View installed updates and from there was able find and uninstall IE11 update. After Restarting PC it automatically downgraded it back to IE8.

[image]

Then Search Internet

[image]